# Elasticsearch Kibana is in Red Status

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

Hi when I access to kibana I get this:

Status: **Red**

[image]

Anyone know what happens to Elasticsearch/Kibana? Or what I should do to fix this?

PS. I am using elasticsearch 5.1.1

Comment: Judging by what's visible in the status breakdown table, your ES server seems to be down or unreachable. Can you curl ES from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Kibana is unable to communicate with Elasticsearch. The Kibana logs should give you more insight into the issue.

The `elasticsearch` section of the `kibana.yml` defines how to connect to Elasticsearch. `elasticsearch.url` specifies the URL of the Elasticsearch instance. From the machine running Kibana, you should be able to access this URL.

For example, using cURL:

```
> curl http://localhost:9200
{
  "name" : "sRp21hL",
  "cluster_name" : "docker-cluster",
  "cluster_uuid" : "ZGmAUJMwRP-txHNr73vcNg",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "7.0.0-alpha1",
    "build_hash" : "ba9e2e4",
    "build_date" : "2018-01-23T14:08:40.916181Z",
    "build_snapshot" : true,
    "lucene_version" : "7.2.1",
    "minimum_wire_compatibility_version" : "6.3.0",
    "minimum_index_compatibility_version" : "6.0.0-beta1"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We have resolved this issue with below steps:

1. Execute the below command to get process are running on port number
   Command: **lsof -i tcp:5600**  (5600 is port number)
2. Kill the processes running
3. Do a fresh Kibana restart